# How to improve image indexing

Tags: google-search-console, images, google-image-search

I have a curious problem:
In Google Webmaster Tools, it shows that from my sitemap 330 images submitted and only 6 are indexed.

I try to put alt tags, descriptive names, everything by the book, but still no results.

What can you suggest to improve image indexing by Google or any other search engine :).